# Compress many numbers into a string

Tags: algorithm, compression

I was wondering if there's a way to compress 20 or so large numbers (~10^8) into a string of a reasonable length. For instance, if the numbers were stored as hex and concatenated, it'd  be at least 160 characters long. I wonder if there's a smart way to compress the numbers in and get them back out. I was thinking about having a sequence 0-9 as reference and let one part of the input string be a number <1024. That number is to be converted to binary, which serves as a mask, i.e. indicating which digits exist in the number. It's still not clear where to go on from here.

Are there any better alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Encryption and compression are two ddifferent things, which are you asking about? (If it's compression, the answer is "that's not possible, in general".)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I should be asking about compression rather than encryption. How come it's generally not possible with compression?

Comment: Because of the *pigeonhole principle*.

Comment: What's a 'string' here?  Is it a sequence of printable characters, or is it a sequence of bytes?  What values are allowed for the individual characters?  The general solution is to represent your input values in Basis(number_of_different_values_for_each_character).

Answer (score 0):

If these large numbers are of the same size in bytes, and if you always know the count of those numbers, there is an easy way to do it. You simply Have an array of your bytes, and instead of reading them out as integers, you read them out as characters. Are you trying to obfuscate your values or just pack them to be easily transferred?

Comment: Then the theory I provided will work just fine, and will be smaller in size then treating the numbers as strings.

Comment: It's to help transfer, but I just want to cut the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm compacting a lot of values into one, reversible `String`, I usually go with `base 64` conversion. This can really cut off quite a lot of the length from a `String`, but note that it may take up just as much memory in representing it.

**Example**

This number in decimal:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

is the following in Base 64:

```
Yki8xQRRVqd403ldXJUT8Ungkh/A3Th2TMtNlpwLPYVgct2eE8MAn0bs4o/fv1bmo4oUNQa/9WtZ8gRE7IG+UHX+LniaQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

**Why you can't do this too an extreme level**

Think about it for a second. Let's say you've got a number of length `10`. And you want to represent that number with `5` characters, so a `50%` rate compression scheme. First, we work out how many possible numbers you can represent with `10` digits.. which is..

```
2^10 = 1024
```

Okay, that's fine. How many numbers can we express with `5 digits`:

```
2^5 = 32
```

So, you can only *display* 32 different numbers with `5` bits, whereas you can display `1024` numbers with `10` bits. For compression to work, there needs to be some mapping between the compressed value and the extracted value. Let's try and make that mapping happen..

```
Normal - Compressed
0        0
1        1
2        2
..       ...
31       31
32       ??
33       ??
34       ??
...      ... 
1023     ??
```

There is no mapping for most of the numbers that can be represented by the expanded value.

This is known as the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and in this example our value for `n` is greater than our value for `m`, hence we need to map values from our compressed values to more than one normal value, which makes things incredibly complex. *(thankyou Oli for reminding me)*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My main object isn't quite to reduce memory usage, but simply to reduce length though.

Comment: Then `base64` might be a good approach for you. It reduces it by quite a bit, and you can map between the original numbers and the `base64` encoded version.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong: I'm using http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp to encode your input, but it turns out to be MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw...

Comment: Instead of converting it from a `String`, interpret it as a number: http://convertxy.com/index.php/numberbases/

Comment: For some input data a minimized trie that handles cycles can be an option. Then base64 that trie. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be much more descriptive about what you mean by "string" and "~10^8".  Can your "string" contain any sequence of bytes?  Or is it restricted to a subset of possible bytes?  If so, how exactly is it restricted?  What are the limits on your "large numbers"?  What do they represent?

Numbers up to 10<sup>8</sup> can be represented in 27 bits.  20 of them would be 540 bits, which could be stored in a string of 68 bytes, if any sequence of bytes is permitted.  If the contents of a string are limited, it will take more bits.  If your range of numbers is larger, it will take more bits.

Answer (score 0):

- store all numbers as strings to a marisa trie: https://code.google.com/p/marisa-trie/
- Base64 the resulting trie dictionary

It depends of course a lot on your input. But it is a possibility to build a (very) compact representation this way.